# Paypal: Passing Customer Name

Tags: variables, paypal

I am creating a simple form with paypal checkout. I am looking to pass an additional name that is not the billing name to the checkout page. Is there any Paypal variable I may have over looked?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic PayPal Standard Button HTML Variables Guide From the PayPal Developer site:
[PayPal Standard Button HTML Variables Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Here is some basic Open PayPal Standard Source Button Code that can pass a customer name and customer phone number:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">Enter Amount<br />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Enter Amount">
<input type="text"   name="amount" size=8>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted"><br />
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Client Name">Enter Client Name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Client Phone">Enter Client Phone Number (no dashes or special characters)</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This part of the button code controls passing the Client Name and Client Phone number to PayPal:

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Client Name">Enter Client Name</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Client Phone">Enter Client Phone Number (no dashes or special characters)</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
```